# Ktor client: Processing errors with code 200

Tags: android, kotlin, multiplatform, ktor

Our server responses to business errors with code 200 and the following body:

```
{
    "success": false,
    "error_code": 1,
    "error_text": "Error message"
}
```

How can I detect this body in responses and throw exception for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `HttpResponseValidator` feature for that: https://ktor.io/clients/http-client/features/response-validation.html

Somethig like that:

```
HttpResponseValidator {
    validateResponse { response ->
       val body = // ...
       check(body.success)
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I knew about validator, but I had problems with getting body from the response, I solved this with Json.parseJson(String(response.readBytes())), but thank you, also, for some reason response.conent.getText() throws error "response already received"